# Can I use Apple UI Kit on an Android app?

Tags: android, ios

Am I able to use the Apple UI Kit on Android like SF Font, native back button but translated to be used on Android or things like navigation style?

I mean with the licenses, if it is ok to use it on a non-Apple environtment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that Apple has not released the UIKit for Android.
The long answer is that you could use parts of it, but it would be pointless and difficult.
Let's look at the elements:

The native back button is simply a back arrow, you can make a copy of it with whatever design language you're using
There is no translation of the navigation style
SF Font is a proprietary Apple font, so you can't use it on Android

The only useful part of UIKit would be the icons, and you can find them in the system UI repository.
I highly recommend you not use UIKit on Android.